# anyone getting "IPN warning" emails from PayPal?

Tags: payment-processor, paypal, ipn

About two months ago, we started getting the following notifications 2x/day via email from PayPal. It appears Civi returns response 200 (error) for non-recurring transactions rather than 500 response (success). The email from PPL says they may disable our account if the issue continues so I'm really worried. We had a pro look at the code, saying there should not be an IPN call for non-recurring transactions, and that Civi throws the error because it doesn't expect it. He's also saying the Civi code handling this hasn't been touch for a long time, and that it's possibly on the PayPal side. We certainly haven't changed any PPL settings ... so wondering if anyone else is seeing these warning emails from PPL:

> Please check your server that handles PayPal Instant Payment
>   Notifications (IPN). IPNs sent to the following URL(s) are failing:
>   https:///civicrm/extern/ipn.php  If you do not
>   recognize this URL, you may be using a service provider that is using
>   IPN on your behalf. Please contact your service provider with the
>   above information. If this problem continues, IPNs may be disabled for
>   your account.  Thank you for your prompt attention to this issue.
>   Thanks, PayPal

Anyone, anyone?

Comment: We are also seeing this on CiviCRM 5.5. When we were using 4.7.x and prior it was not an issue.

Comment: The URL you pasted seems to be wrong for ipn call back! Did you trim the url?

Comment: Sorry, yes, the full IPN URL in PayPal is: <our site URL>/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/extern/ipn.php; this is a Joomla implementation; the URL is correct - a 3rd party Civi developer who looked at the code and logs said the calls from PayPal are reaching Civi, but apparently it should NOT be doing so for non-recurring payments; and since Civi is not expecting a call from PayPal, it freaks out and sends an error to PayPal. Seems odd to me, but that's what I'm being told

Comment: @MtnPavlas I'm running into the same issue.  Who was the professional developer you spoke with?  maybe we can combine our efforts to a solution

Comment: There have been improvements to the paypal IPNs during the 5.x release cycle.  However, this is most likely a pre-existing issue and may require changes to the IPN processor in CiviCRM to "ignore" or send a 200 OK response to paypal for non-recurring transactions.

Comment: @CiviTeacher, sorry about the late reply; please see if the answer I posted and accepted as a solution works for you; if not, I worked with Jitendra from Fuzion

Comment: We're seeing this

MtnPavlas is the fix Fuzion implemented still working for you? Did you by chance try configuring PayPal with the newer IPN URL? 

https://example.com/civicrm/payment/ipn/NN

@MatthewWire would this new IPN URL have any effect on Civi's response to the unexpected IPN call?

Comment: How can I stop getting Emails from PayPal, I keep getting them every 2 minutes, please make them stop thank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for the confirmation others are seeing this issue. In the end, this solved it for us - add lines 4-6 from the following code (lines 1-3 and 7-9 included for reference) to file /CRM/Core/Payment/PayPalProIPN.php

```
CRM_Core_Error::debug_var('GET', $_GET, TRUE, TRUE);
CRM_Core_Error::debug_var('POST', $_POST, TRUE, TRUE);
if ($this->_isPaymentExpress) {
  if (empty($this->_inputParameters['rp_invoice_id'])) {
    return;
  }
  $this->handlePaymentExpress();
  return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: has this been suggested as a patch to CiviCRM?

Comment: I was told by the person who fixed this for us that it would be, but I don't see this change in the 5.9.0 version so guessing it hasn't happened yet; if you know how to submit the patch, please do; in the meantime, I can nudge the developer in question

Comment: It may not have been submitted as a patch because a similar or same issue and solution is being discussed: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/659

Answer (score 1):

I've been seeing this in various versions of CiviCRM starting in roughly Sep of this year.  Note in the original post that actually 500=error vs. 200=success, but other than that, the description of the symptom I'm seeing is accurate.  I think that (just guessing) something has changed in the way that Paypal is using the IPN URL - and sending it things it didn't used to.  What happens, after 100 failures, is that Paypal will stop sending IPN completely, and you must re-enable IPN via the Paypal.com 'profile' console.

Answer (score 0):

Just upgraded from 4.7.27 --> 5.8.1 and have now started seeing the issue with all non-recurring payments returning an error to PayPal.  Then PayPal disabled IPNs for all payments, including recurring.

I had to copy `civicrm/CRM/Core/Payment/PayPalProIPN.php` from the old version to "solve" the problem.

I also saw this in the logs:

`PHP Warning:  array_flip(): Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values! in /sites/example.com/production/current/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Payment/PayPalProIPN.php on line 214

PHP Stack trace:

PHP   1. {main}() /sites/example.com/production/current/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/extern/ipn.php:0

PHP   2. CRM_Core_Payment_PayPalProIPN->main() /sites/example.com/production/current/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/extern/ipn.php:59

PHP   3. CRM_Core_Payment_PayPalProIPN->handlePaymentExpress() /sites/example.com/production/current/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Payment/PayPalProIPN.php:428

PHP   4. CRM_Core_Payment_PayPalProIPN->recur() /sites/example.com/production/current/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Payment/PayPalProIPN.php:602

PHP   5. array_flip() /sites/example.com/production/current/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Payment/PayPalProIPN.php:214`