# PayPal Pro IPN returns 403 error

Tags: payment-processor, paypal, recurring-contributions, payment

Have been receiving email from PayPal that IPN is not working. One off donations were updated but not recurring payments. I am on CiviCRM 5.16.4

How can I fix it please?

I have tried this but still not working 
[anyone getting "IPN warning" emails from PayPal?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/26603/292)

EDIT: Content of the email, also added a screenshot of the paypal IPN screen

```
Dear Tapash Datta , 

Please check your server that handles PayPal Instant Payment Notifications (IPN). Instant Payment Notifications sent to the following URL(s) are failing:

https://example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/extern/ipn.php 

If you do not recognize this URL, you may be using a service provider that is using IPN on your behalf. Please contact your service provider with the above information. If this problem continues, IPNs may be disabled for your account. 

Thank you for your prompt attention to this issue.

Yours sincerely, 

PayPal
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post the content of the email you getting from Paypal. You can remove sensitive information from the email while posting

Comment: @PradeepNayak Thanks. Added more info in the post

Answer (score 3):

Having reviewed this I believe that your Paypal is possibly configured to point to an older version of the IPN path.

You can change this yourself within your Paypal account, the docs I can see suggest:

To configure Instant Payments Notification (IPN) for your PayPal account Click: Profile, under Selling preferences click "Instant Payment Notification preferences"
It looks like yours is currently set to: https://domain.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm/extern/ipn.php

However, it should now be set as: https://domain.org/civicrm/payment/ipn/3 where 3 is the payment processor id which you can get from Payment Processor screen(Administrator >> System Settings >> Payment Processor). This should fix any new payments setup / made.

For recurring payments that have already been setup what you would need to do is make a change to the site so that those old / failed recurring payments get [forced onto the new path](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/473/how-to-change-paypal-ipn-url-when-migrating-civicrm-onto-a-new-domain/4326#4326), once you've done that you'll need to ['replay' all the previously failed recurring payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNOperations/#view-ipn-messages-and-details) from Paypal terminal. Depending on the number of transactions involved, this may involve some work from yourself in the Paypal site again. Or the other method is to [use Notification log extension](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/4510/155) to do replay of failed transaction.

Cheers

Pradeep

Comment: Thanks @PradeepNayak. But this didnt work. I have chnaged the Rewrite rule and resent the IPN, but still no luck.

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: I have chnaged URL to - https://example.com/civicrm/payment/ipn/1 in PP IPN settings, When IPN resent - I still get 403 error, with status FAILED. 
I have added in .htaccess - RewriteRule ^sites/all/modules/civicrm/extern/ipn.php$  https://example.com/civicrm/payment/ipn/1 [R=307,L]

RewriteRule https://example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/extern/ipn.php$  https://example.com/civicrm/payment/ipn/1 [R=307,L]

I have tried with both relative & absolute url. but still no luck.